# modeling a one or many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I was wondering how I could model the following relationship in mysql. The following ERD shows my design

[image]

An Order has `strictly one` product and a product `has many` orders

This is what I have so far and not really sure how I can enforce the constraints

```
-- Order table
CREATE TABLE Order (
  orderId INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  date DATETIME,
  serialNumber INT NOT NULL
);

-- Address table
CREATE TABLE Product (
  serial_No INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  manufacturer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ram VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

 -- Join table
 CREATE TABLE Order_Product (
     id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     orderId INT NOT NULL,
     serial_No INT NOT NULL
 );
```

Comment: Looks like you cannot have an Order without a Product linked to it. So you might want to include a Product column in your Order table, rather than have a mapping table.

Comment: Correct. From your information, this is a one-to-many relationship, so adding an extra column should be enough. If it were many-to-many, then it would require the additional mapping table as in your proposed design.

Comment: Sorry accidentally deleted my previous comment so it invalidates your comment :-(

Comment: How do you handle the has_many relationship of this. Do I need a mapping table for that or no need?...

Comment: No need. Make Products a non-null column in Orders. Index it to improve search efficiency. Then, every time you want to see what Orders were placed for a Product, just search by the Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, you want something like below. Then, create a foreign key constraint enforcing that the value of Order.productSerial must be a valid serial_NO from Product. (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). You can `SELECT * FROM Order where productSerial = (whatever)` to find all orders of a product, or do JOINs between Order.productSerial and Product.serial_No.

```
-- Order table
CREATE TABLE Order (
  orderId INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  productSerial INT(6) NOT NULL,
  date DATETIME,
  serialNumber INT NOT NULL
);

-- Address table
CREATE TABLE Product (
  serial_No INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  manufacturer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ram VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I dont think what you have depicts a FK relationship. The `serial_No` that you have can simply be anything. Are you saying something like `serialNumber INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (serialNumber) REFERENCES Product(serial_No)`,

Comment: I didn't include the creation of the foreign key, I left at for OP to decide because I can't say what ON DELETE rule he'd want, etc. But yes, something like what you wrote is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

See , As it is one to many relationship foreign key is enough to statisfy your requirement. In case of many to many relationship addtional table is required to perform relationship.

so this will work :

```
CREATE TABLE Order (
  orderId INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  serial_No INT(6) UNSIGNED ,
  date DATETIME,
  serialNumber INT NOT NULL ,
  foreign key(serial_No) references product(serial_No)
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
  serial_No INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  manufacturer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ram VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
);
```

And use Join or Subquery to get related data.

For Ex :

Product :

Serial_No    manufacture

1001         Dell

1002         HP

Oder :

orderid   Serial_no

101       1001

102       1002

103       1001